# How to add more than 3 fields in link master and child fields?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a subreport where I have 3 fields in the link parent and child field. I need to add one more field in there. Is there a way to have more than 3 linked fields?

Comment: So you want 4 fields in a compound key? I expect do that the same way as for 3 fields. Type what you need to in the properties. Show the links you currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the subform Property Sheet, an ellipsis (...) button appears next to the *Link Master Field* and *Link Child Field* property values.  Clicking that button displays the *Subform Field Linker* popup dialogue window.  That window supports specifying up to 3 field pairs.

If you add more than one field pair in the *Subform Field Linker* and then click Okay, notice that both the *Link Master Field* and *Link Child Field* fields are populated with **semicolon-delimited list of field names**.

To add more field pairs, just follow the pattern:  **Add a forth pair of fields to *Link Master Field* and *Link Child Field* properties, separated from the other field names by a semicolon.**  Those properties can both be edited directly without clicking on the button.